# 404 error as JSON format, POSTMAN gives default error template instead of JSON content

Tags: rest, api, coldfusion, postman, coldfusion-2018

I have tried one undefined rest path through ColdFusion Rest Playground and it gives response like below;

```
{
    "MESSAGE": "Not Found",
    "STATUS": 404
}
```

When I am trying the same from POSTMAN, its gives 404 server error!

server error
404 - File or directory was not found.
The resource you are looking for may have been removed, renamed, or temporarily unavailable.

Tried using Accept header as application/json, but its not working.

Here is the configuration of REST Service;

```
Root Path                           Service Mapping     Default     Host:Port
D:\Projects\restSample\             v1                  NO          my.restAPI

REST Path
rest
```

And the URL I have tried;

```
http://my.restAPI/rest/v1/api/test => Working
http://my.restAPI/rest/v1/api/test1 => Gives 404 (but not JSON)
```

api.cfc

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="api">
     <cffunction name="getTest" restpath="test" access="remote" returntype="struct" httpmethod="GET" produces="application/json">
         <cfset var response = {} />
         <cfset response["message"] = "Test" />
         <cfreturn response>
     </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

How can I get the response as JSON format in POSTMAN for http://my.restAPI/rest/v1/api/test1?

Comment: Could you please post your rest path / url details ? About your configuration in rest services in cfadmin. etc...

Comment: @Kannan.P Updated the question.

Comment: Where is your rest path test1 details ?

Comment: There is no definition for that path. I have to do the error handling when the rest path is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `Error model` class consisting of details such as `Error code, message,  HTTP status codes` or any additional information you want to return during the course of an exception or to be specific [Resource not found].

In case of  http://my.restAPI/rest/v1/api/test1

***Assuming, test1 is a resource (you are requesting or creating) which doesn't exist***.

The response should be your `Error model` filled up with all information, as part of exception handling or code validation!